# How can I return a reference of RefCell<String> as &str with lifetime of the Struct in which the RefCell is declared?

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn Rust. I have the following problem, I am trying to get a reference of a RefCell<String> as &str with lifetime of the struct in which the RefCell is declared.
Snippets of code are below, (code is taken from Rust book)

```rust
trait State {
    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {""}
    fn add_text(&self, content: RefCell<String>,text: &str) {}
}
struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: RefCell<String>,
}

struct Published {}
struct Draft {}

impl Published {
    pub fn content(&self) -> &str{
        self.state.as_ref().unwrap().content(&self)
    }
     fn add_text(&self, text: &str) {
        self.state
            .as_ref()
            .unwrap()
            .add_text(RefCell::clone(&self.content), text);
    }
}

impl State for Published {
    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        &post.content.borrow().as_str() "**//Line of error**"

    }
}
impl State for Draft {
    fn add_text(&self, content: RefCell<String>, text: &str) {
        &content.borrow_mut().push_str(text);
    }
}
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
error[E0515]:
cannot return value referencing temporary value
  src/lib.rs:113:9
113 |&post.content.borrow().as_str()
temporary value created here
returns a value referencing data owned by the current
```

The line of the error is commented in the code.

Could someone explain me please what I am doing wrong, and why?

What I am trying to achieve is to another Trait to be able to mutate the content String of the Post struct, and another Trait also to return it.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Please post more of that compiler error giving it more context.

Comment: You cannot. It is simple.

Comment: @trojanfoe added, hope it makes sense, I couldn't manage to format it

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I added more code,  could you explain please what I am doing wrong and why? What other solution can I use to achieve it.

Comment: How is the `RefCell` supposed to be notified your `&str` goes out of scope? It can't therefore your code can't work.

Comment: Your interface as written permits dangling pointers, so the compiler will not allow it. Suppose that I do `let a = post.content()` to get a reference to the underlying string, then `post.add_text("...")`, and this causes the `String` to re-allocate its internal buffer because there isn't enough space. But `post` is still valid and so my reference `a : &str` is still valid, but is in fact dangling, since the String de-allocates the old buffer when it grows.

Comment: You *can* return `impl Deref<Target = str>`without breaking encapsulation using [`Ref::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map)